# Icon is not changed after update of an app

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, itunes

I have created a new version of iPhone app. I wanted to change the icon, so:

- I added the icons in different sized to the Resources folder of my Project in XCode:

[image]

- I specified the icon files in the info.plist file:

[image]

- in iTunes Connect I added new version of my app and replace the old icon with the new one. The new icon is now visible when I log in to iTunes Connect.

The effects:

- I can see the new icon when I run my app on simulator.
- I can see the new icon when I visit AppStore with iTunes on my Mac.
- I can see the OLD icon when I visit AppStore on my iPhone.
- I can see the OLD icon on my iPhone after upgrading my app to the new version.

Any ideas why the old icon is still visible in some of the places?

kind regards,
Jakub

Answer (score 5):

Use "Build > Clean all Targets" and then build and run. Xcode doesn't always see that images have been updated, and leaves them out of incremental builds. Cleaning before building makes Xcode build the app file from scratch, and will pick up any images it's failing to get.

Why it's inconsistent is that different build types (simulator vs device) are different build targets, and got built with different versions of your images. Not unusual.

The one thing that this WON'T address is the old icon on the iPhone's app store app. You might need to update your app store submission with fresh images.